# using GPU under multiple task

Tags: parallel-processing, f#, gpu

I have an application which has multiple threads.  Will there be problems with executing computations using AleaCubase on each of the threads simultaneously and is there any performance benefit to doing so?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "serialize it".  Are you saying you want to know how AleaCubase will handle multiple simultaneous tasks accessing the GPU at the same time?

Comment: yes... will that be safe and give significant speedup.

Comment: I've edited your question for clarity.

Comment: I want to explore parallelism provided by GPU while utilizing parallel construct of F#.
if that is possible, 
then I can go for any framework which will facilitate this.
if you can suggest any?

Comment: Generally speaking, asking for an off-site resource is off-topic for stackoverflow.  Your original question is much more specific and has a concrete answer, so you should stick with that one.